# How "links" instruction work in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In the below `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
app:
  build: ../../
  dockerfile: docker/release/Dockerfile
  links:
    - dbc
  volumes_from:
    - webroot
  environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: someapp.settings.release
    MYSQL_HOST: db
    MYSQL_USER: user1
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: passwd
  command:
    - uwsgi
    - "--socket /var/www/someapp/someapp.sock"
    - "--chmod-socket=666"
    - "--module someapp.wsgi"
    - "--master"
    - "--die-on-term"

dbc:
  image: mysql:5.6
  hostname: db
  expose:
    - "3386"
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: someapp
    MYSQL_USER: user1
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: passwd
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: passwd
```

---

there is dependency of `app` service on `dbc` service.

```
  links:
    - dbc
```

But, app cannot connect to database, with the above syntax.

We had written a ansible probe as a separate container service, that does:

```
wait_for host={{ probe_host }}
      port={{ probe_port }}
```

---

What does `links` exactly ensure?

Answer (score 1):

Docker links are only necessary for the [legacy "default bridge network" mode](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#use-the-default-bridge-network).  Docker Compose will [automatically create a "user-defined bridge network"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and so **`links:` are never necessary in `docker-compose.yml` files**.

In practice, this means that `links:` acts exactly like [`depends_on:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on).  If you run `docker-compose up app`, it will also start `dbc` for you.  Compose will start starting the database before it starts starting your application, but it has no way to know that the database is done starting; typically you use a script like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to ensure the database is ready, or set a [`restart:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart) policy and just crash if the database isn't accessible yet.

For a container `a` to reach a container `b` in the same `docker-compose.yml` file, the only requirement is that they be on the same network.  The easiest way to accomplish this is for neither to have a `networks:` block at all.  If they both do, they must have some name in common, and if only one does, it must contain `default`.  The service names (in your example, `app` and `dbc`) will be usable as ordinary hostnames, with no further configuration required by you.  Setting `hostname:` has no effect on networking; `container_name:` will provide an additional name for the container; neither option is necessary.

Regardless of any other settings, inter-container communications always use whatever port the server process inside the container is listening on.  Neither `ports:` nor `expose:` are required; if you have `ports:` and the two port numbers are different, you'll connect to the *second* port number.  For the `mysql:5.6` image you show, you will always connect to port 3306 (exposing a different port number has no effect).

In most cases, you should never specify `links:`, `expose:`, `hostname:` or `container_name:`; they're unnecessary for networking and don't set useful properties of the containers.  I'd also recommend just using the default network setup, and never specifying `networks:` anywhere in the file.

Comment: For your point: "In most cases, you should never specify..." Can you comment on this query? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58617998/3317808